# How to make a tuple with components belonging to a type class an instance II

Tags: haskell, ghc, typeclass

This is modification of a question a just ask some minutes ago - but for this situation I got problems...

I have the following problem: I defined a type class and want to declare tuples of types of this class to be instances as well. But I don't know how to get GHC to accept this declaration. Here a very simple example:

```
class Test x a where
    elm :: a
```

And know for tuples I want to do something like

```
instance (Test x a, Test x b) => Test x (a,b) where
    elm = (elm, elm)
```

Moreover, I am using

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances          #-}
```

The addition type `x` causes the trouble here...
How can this been done?  Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: It can't.  If I call `elm :: Int` there is no way to know if it should use the `instance Test Int Int` vs `instance Test () Int` vs `instance Test FooType Int` vs anything else.  Perhaps you should go up a level of abstraction and ask about the problem that led you down this road.

Comment: That is a bad news... `elm` was supposed to provide a special element of only one of both types. E.g. `instance Test a Int where elm = 0`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing whatsoever to do with tuples. The problem is simply that `x` occurs in the class head, but not the signature of `elm` – so there's no way to determine what to use as the `x` type, when `elm` turns up somewhere in your code.

Indeed, if `elm` is the only method of `Test`, then there's no need to have that `x` parameter at all – simply remove it, and your instance will be fine:

```
class Test a where
  elm :: a
instance (Test a, Test b) => Test (a,b) where
  elm = (elm, elm)
```

More likely, you actually have some other method that does use `x`, like

```
class Test x a where
  elm :: a
  beech :: x -> a
```

In this case, it might make sense to factor out `elm` into a simpler superclass:

```
class PreTest a where
  elm :: a
class (PreTest a) => Test x a where
  beech :: x -> a
```

Alternatively, you can obtain the `x` information in some other way, not through the method's signature. This can be done with a fundep:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}
class Test x a | a->x where
  elm :: a
```

This indicates that there can only be exactly one `Test _ a` instance for any type `a`, hence the compiler can unambiguously infer `x` from it.

But I heavily suspect that you don't really want that – such a class is much less flexible than a full two-parameter class. Modern Haskell tends to favour the largely equivalent associated type synonyms over fundep MultiParamTypeClasses, and mostly uses MTPCs when `x` and `a` are really two independent parameters.

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes, factoring out sound very good - I will tried for my real example (a typeclass for a vector space of some field)!  (Actually, I though about using the FunctionalDependencies, but this is indeed not want I really want!)